# List remove Method Removing Last Row Upon Deleting Rows from Table

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to delete a row based on the Rowindex, but whenever i try deleting first time the first row it delete's the last row when first tried after that it works good.

Note: Issue is occurring only first time when trying to delete..

Please see my code:

===VF page===

```
  <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Showtable4}" id="block4" >

       <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2}" var="o" id="table" rendered="{!listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2.size>0}">

    <apex:column headerValue="No." style="width:20px; text-align:center;" headerClass="centertext">
        <apex:outputText value="{0}" style="text-align:center;"> 
        <apex:param value="{!rowNumber +1}" /> 
        </apex:outputText>
        </apex:column> 

       <!-- <apex:column >            
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!o.selected}" id="inputId"/>
            </apex:column> -->

          <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" >
            <apex:outputField value="{!o.BR_Opportunity__r.Account.Name}" id="field1">
            <apex:inlineEditSupport />
            </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>
               <apex:column headerValue="Híbrido" >
            <apex:outputField value="{!o.BR_Hybrid__c}" id="field2">
            <apex:inlineEditSupport />
            </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>


            <apex:column headerValue="Action" >

            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="block4" immediate="true" status="load">
            <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>

           <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addBags}" immediate="true" status="load" reRender="block4">
            <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>

            </apex:commandButton>-->
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>
            </apex:column> 


     </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

===controller Method Code==

```
public void deleteRow(){

     rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
     System.debug('rowbe deleted ' + rowIndex );
          System.debug('rowbe deleted ' + listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2);

     System.debug('rowm to be deleted@@@@@@ '+listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2[rowIndex]);
          System.debug('TestSfdcName'+listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2[rowIndex].BR_Opportunity__r.Account.Name);

    // System.debug('%%%%%%%%%%%%% '+listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2);

        // if (!(listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands.size() < rowIndex)&& listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands.size()>0 ){
         //    listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands.remove(rowIndex);
    // }
     System.debug('size' + listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2.size());

    // if (!(listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2.size() < rowIndex) ){

       //System.debug('prateek'+listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2.remove(rowIndex));
          System.debug('TestSfdcName2'+listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2[rowIndex].BR_Opportunity__r.Account.Name);
     System.debug('rowm to be deleted@@@@@@ '+listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2[rowIndex]);
     System.debug('Index ' + rowIndex );

             listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2.remove(rowIndex);

                  System.debug('removed Index ' + rowIndex );

                  System.debug('removed '+listBagsBrandAndOtherBrands2.remove(rowIndex).BR_Opportunity__r.Account.Name);

    // }
    }
```

Please suggest what is Going wrong here..

Comment: Not much clear what you are asking, however in this model you can only delete the last row since `rowIndex` is always having the count of the list elements

Comment: Hi Highfive, thanks for your update ...what i am trying to achieve here capability of adding and removing Rows dynamically on a click of button on pageblocktable...but here the problem is when i am first trying to delete row using the rowindex its deleting the last row in table..

Answer (score 1):

When you have a count variable inside your `pageBlockTable`, always it will have the item count value. But in your case the `apex:param` should pass the row index individually to the controller. I can't think of doing this without having a wrapper class. Try understand the below design. You have to have separate values in each row. The `reArrangeIndexes` function is to regenerate the row indexes after a deletion happen. If not you will encounter ArrayOutOfBound exceptions.

Controller

```
public class myController{
    public List<WrapperClass> wrapperList{get;set;}
    public Integer indexToDelete{get;set;}

    //function to populate wrapper list
    public void populateWrapperList(){
        Integer i = 0; //variable to set the list item index

        //perform your search query and let say the result is itemList
        for(YourObject item : itemList){
            WrapperClass wrapper = new WrapperClass();
            wrapper.index = i++;
            //set other wrapper class fields

            wrapperList.add(wrapper);           
        }
    }

    //function to delete item from wrapper list
    public void deleteItemFromWrapperList(){
        if(wrapperList != null && wrapperList.size() <= indexToDelete ){
            wrapperList.remove(index);
        }
    }

    //function to reset indexes
    public void reArrangeIndexes(){
        Integer i = 0;
        for(WrapperClass wrapper : wrapperList){
            wrapper.index = i++;
        }
    }

    public class WrapperClass{
        //have all your field to bind with UI here. i.e. BR_Hybrid__c, Account Name, etc.
        public Integer index{get;set;}  //to track the index in the wrapper list
    }
}
```

Page part:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrapper" id="table" rendered="{!wrapperList!=null && wrapperList.size>0}">

    <!-- Have your other columns here and access values through 'wrapper' variable  -->

    <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteItemFromWrapperList}" reRender="block4" status="load">
        <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!wrapper.index}" assignTo="{!indexToDelete}"/>
    </apex:commandButton>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```